# save all state and view when fragmenttransaction

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i use fragment for my application,they are : Fragment A, Fragment B and Fragment C.

to move from one fragment to another fragment, I use two buttons, the first button is used to forward to the next fragment, and the second button is used to return to the previous fragment.

the problems when I move from one fragment to another fragment (such as from A to B and back to A and go to B again ). all entries in the EditText of `Fragment B`  is lost and look back empty. this is Fragment A:

```
public class AFragment extends Fragment {
EditText text,text2;
public AFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
    ImageView next=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.next);
    text=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    text2=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

              getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new TertanggungPolis()).addToBackStack("" + new BFragment().getId()).commit();


        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

i have made save method `onSaveInstanceState` but nothing change in my fragment B when fragment transaction from A-B-A-B again, `fragment B` just create new view,and all editext that i've input before i back to `fragment A` is missing, this is my fragment B :

```
 public class BFragment extends Fragment {
EditText cut,cut2;
public BFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View Fragment B = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_c, container, false);
    ImageView next=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.next);
    ImageView prev=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.prev);
    cut=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.cut);
    cut2=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.cut2);
    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

              getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new CFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();


        }
    });
    prev.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                    getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

        }
    });
    return Fragment B;
}
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        onSaveInstanceState(new Bundle());      
    }
       public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(state);
                state.putString("text 1",cut.getText().toString());
                state.putString("text 2",cut2.getText().toString());
}
}
```

please help me, i have so frustased and stress because of this. i hope someone can help me to solve my problem, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

you have to save your state into the `Bundle` in the Method [`onSaveInstanceState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29), like you do now (add the `@Override` annotation, because you are overriding an existing method). And you need to restore the state in the [`onActivityCreated()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated%28android.os.Bundle%29) method. Load your values from the `Bundle` and set them to your EditText fields.
Add something like this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onActivityCreated(bundle);
    if(bundle != null){
        //state can be restored
        //load values and set them to your view elements
        String loaded = bundle.getString("text 1");
        cut.setText(loaded);
    } else {
        //The fragment is created the first time and no state was saved before
    }
}
```

you can also Read about the [life-cycle of Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle).

Comment: on my case, how to restored my editext value? thank you

Comment: my view still not load anything, where is exactly i call method onActivityCreated()  and onSaveInstanceState()?

Comment: i try to log it, i got value from method of onSaveInstanceState(), but not from onActivityCreated() :(

Comment: you never call `onActivityCreated()`, it's called by the android system. Please read about the Fragments lifecycle http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html